Is there anywhere mentioned in Scriptures that Laws of Universe emanates from Brahman?
Namaste,
Is there anywhere mentioned in Hindu scriptures that Brahman is the source of all the cosmic Laws such as Law of Karma?
I sincerely request if anyone can please share appropriate references from Scriptures
Thanks
